# Passing Object to Thread fails - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, udp

I've been trying to pass an object to my main thread process but it seems it will not work in the way I thought it would.

First I create the Thread:

```
Thread thrUDP;
```

Then I create the object I will use to store the data I need:

```
UDPData udpData;
```

Now I Initialize the object withthe correct data, Set up the new thread and start it with the object passed into the Start() method:

```
udpData = new UDPData("224.5.6.7", "5000", "0", "2");

            thrUDP = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SendStatus));
            thrUDP.Start(udpData);
```

This is the method I wish to start:

```
private void SendStatus(UDPData data)
{
}
```

I remember using Threads a while back and I'm sure they weren't so difficult to pass data to, am I doing this the wrong way or am I just missing a piece of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ParameterizedThreadStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) delegate is declared as:

```
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(object obj);
```

Clearly, this delegate isn't compatible with your method's signature, and  there isn't a direct way to get a `System.Threading.Thread` to work with an arbitrary delegate-type.

One of your options would be to use a compatible signature for the method, and cast as appropriate:

```
private void SendStatus(object obj)
{
   UDPData data = (UDPData)obj;
   ...
}
```

The other option would be to punt the problem to the C# compiler, creating a closure. For example:

```
new Thread(() => SendStatus(udpData)).Start();
```

Do note that this uses the `ThreadStart` delegate instead. Additionally, you should be careful with subsequently modifying the `udpData` local, since it is captured.

Alternatively, if you don't mind using the thread-pool instead of spawning your own thread, you could use asynchronous delegates. For example:

```
Action<UDPData> action = SendStatus;
action.BeginInvoke(udpData, action.EndInvoke, null);
```

Comment: Ahh, so I simply needed to change the parameter type and then cast it to the correct type in the method! Thanks =]

Comment: I disagree - usually the class should create the new thread inside itself - creating threads from outside is a recipe for desaster from my pov if synchronisiation is getting complex.

Comment: @weismat: What do you mean by "inside itself", exactly?

Comment: If you work with a static method, then an external thread creation is okay, if you invoke a method of another class, then it is better to invoke the thread inside the other class and not outside.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void SendStatus(object data)
{
 UDPData myData = (UDPData) data;
}
```